# Obtaining a Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can I obtain a command block without using any minecraft plugins? I want to do this on a vanilla server and I'm not too sure how.

Comment: If I can get a quick answer that would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command blocks are easily obtainable through vanilla minecraft. Open your chat box and type

```
/give @p minecraft:command_block
```

This is a command which gives you a block, which in this case is a command block. You can give other players command blocks by replacing `@p` with their username.

Cheats must be enabled for this to work, so go to settings and "open to lan" if necessary.

Comment: If you're ever curious for the future you can use this command to attain any other block otherwise not available in the creative menu, such as barrier blocks.